# Add ramdom value in argument link

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, caching

I try to make the argument value "? v=" ramdom on the example below to avoid the cache (Cache-Buster mode) in page Default.aspx

If the page had been in php no problem this is simple but the page is in aspx and so html/javascript I don’t see how to do

```
<Html>
<Head>
<meta Http-Equiv="Cache" content="no-cache">
<meta Http-Equiv="Pragma-Control" content="no-cache">
<meta Http-Equiv="Cache-directive" Content="no-cache">
<meta Http-Equiv="Pragma-directive" Content="no-cache">
<meta Http-Equiv="Cache-Control" Content="no-cache">
<meta Http-Equiv="Pragma" Content="no-cache">
<meta Http-Equiv="Expires" Content="0">
<meta Http-Equiv="Pragma-directive: no-cache">
<meta Http-Equiv="Cache-directive: no-cache">
</Head>
<Body>
<marquee><object width="910" height="50" type="text/plain" data="http://sandbox.serveur.prive/test.txt?v=[Here-Value-Ramdom]" border="0" style="overflow: hidden;"></object></marquee>
</Body>
</Html>
```

Thank

Comment: _"but the page is in aspx and so html/javascript"_ - And the problem is? Find a way on how to generate a random number and add it (with the language you want to do this).

Comment: `<marquee>` is deprecated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved my prob.

Thank all

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
        <meta Http-Equiv="Cache" content="no-cache">
        <meta Http-Equiv="Pragma-Control" content="no-cache">
        <meta Http-Equiv="Cache-directive" Content="no-cache">
        <meta Http-Equiv="Pragma-directive" Content="no-cache">
        <meta Http-Equiv="Cache-Control" Content="no-cache">
        <meta Http-Equiv="Pragma" Content="no-cache">
        <meta Http-Equiv="Expires" Content="0">
        <meta Http-Equiv="Pragma-directive: no-cache">
        <meta Http-Equiv="Cache-directive: no-cache">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="webLink">
            <div id="DivAlertePageLogin">
                <marquee>
                        <object id="ObjAlertePageLogin" width="300" height="100" type="text/plain" data="test.txt" border="0" style="overflow: hidden;"></object>
                </marquee>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var newUrl = 'Alerte_PageLogin1.txt';
            var divEl = document.getElementById('DivAlertePageLogin');
            var objEl = document.getElementById('ObjAlertePageLogin');
            objEl.data = newUrl;
            // Refresh the content
            divEl.innerHTML = divEl.innerHTML;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do here is create your object with javascript. Then you will be able to set whatever value in your data attribute.

Replace your body with that (note that I didn't set every attribute of your object):

```
   <body>
     <script>
       // create the object
       const obj = document.createElement("object");
       obj.width = "910"
       obj.height= "50"
       // add any other attributes like that
       // obj.type = ....
       // obj.boder = ..

       // just using a simple random here, but you can probably generate a string also
       obj.data = "http://sandbox.serveur.prive/test.txt?v=" + Math.random()
       // add the element to the body
       document.body.appendChild(obj);
     </script>
   </body>
```

Comment: Thank @AzloD I had not updated the page and see your answer that now I thank you for your answer but I seek if possible something more generic that allows me to add the variable ramdom to the different link on any page and not only to the link of "object" a bit like the PHP example indicate in the answer below. If that is possible?